# Updating value in one Odata Service from another

Tags: odata, sapui5

I want to update value for a field in one Odata service based on the value I received from another service. For some reason my ODataModel.update(spath, oentry, null, success, error) does not work correctly.  I have a feeling I am wrong in stmt 1. But if I do this exact code for Read, it reads the proper order. Challenge is I am not able to update the field for that order.

```
 var sServiceUrl = this.getOwnerComponent().getMetadata().getManifestEntry("sap.app").dataSources["ServiceToBeUpdated"].uri;
                var odataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(sServiceUrl);
                var sPath = "/OrderSet('" + this.orderid + "')"; //1

        var oEntry = {};

            oEntry.FieldToUpdate= fieldfromOtherservice;

            odataModel.update(sPath, oEntry, null,
                 function(data) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                 function(e) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            );
        },
```

Comment: what do you finally get the sPath as? 
What is the error you are getting (if any)

Comment: @NandanChaturvedi  I get sPath = OrdersSet(412345)  which is correct, I am targeting that order only. But in error I get  - "Method 'ORDERSSET_UPDATE_ENTITY' not implemented in data provider class."}

Comment: this means your oData does not support update entity. If you are using Gateway oData try this:

* check the DPC class and method 'ORDERSSET_UPDATE_ENTITY' where you can define the update of oData

Comment: @NandanChaturvedi Thank you very much. I will try that

Comment: sure. I will also add this as an answer to this question for others to refer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue says "UPDATE method is not implemented". This means that:

- There is no handler written in oData implementation for an update request.

You can fix this issue in oData(in SAP Gateway) as follows:

> In the DPC(Data Provider Class) of your oData implementation, go to
>   the **method "ORDERSSET_UPDATE_ENTITY"** and define/redefine it.
>
> Put your implementation code of update entity here and it should then
>   work.

Let me know if this helps.